# using safearealayoutguide or SafeAreaView on BottomTabNavigator to remove white space

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am working on an app and I am using createBottomTabNavigator to create my menu. this is what it looks like on ios 11 and more:

[image]

I am trying to remove white spaces, I made another post which I have removed now and someone suggested to use safearealayoutguide, which I dont where to use.

this is my createBottomTabNavigator:

```
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const BottomTabs = () => (
  <Tab.Navigator
    initialRouteName="Home"
    tabBarOptions={{
      style: {
        borderTopWidth: 0,
      },
      activeBackgroundColor: "#01ba73",
      inactiveBackgroundColor: "#003923",
      showLabel: false,
    }}
  >
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Home"
      ..
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Search"
      ..
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Scanner"
      component={ScannerScreen}
      ..
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Chat"
      ...
    />
    <Tab.Screen
      name="Profile"
      ....
    />
  </Tab.Navigator>
);
```

in my home page if I use SafeAreaView and put everything brtween that doesnt fix the issue, I have seen on this site that I have to use `insets`  I have tried that already but it doenst work.

I am working on expo and I really want to fix this, spend a lot of time on this and still having the same issue. would apperefciate some help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do the below thing in `Tab.Navigator`'s `tabBarOptions`

```
 safeAreaInsets: {
      bottom: 0,
    },
```

But it does not look nice , I guess. Better approach is use SafeAreaView

Comment: Thanks but I have already trid tis and this doesnt work!